# Should a person love only God (Krishna) ? What does Bhagvad Gita say about it?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, love

Should a person love only God (Krishna) ?
What does Bhagvad Gita say about it ?

Is loving other human beings wrong ? Can loving other human beings create attachment ?

Comment: As jivas who identify  ourselves with out bodies, we have an inherent need to worship God through a physical representation. If you love God through another that is sattvic; but to love another as a physical being itself, that leads to further identification with the body and ruin,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Should a person love only God?**

The answer is no. However, if he loves only God then he will be free from suffering.

**Supreme Bliss experienced by a Yogi**

> In which he (the Yogi) experiences that endless bliss which is beyond
> the ken of the senses but is intuited by the purified intellect;
> wherein established, one does not waver from the Truth.

**Gita 6.21**

> Supreme bliss wells up in a Yogi, who is tranquil in mind, whose
> passions are subdued, who is free from impurities and who is in the
> state of Brahmabhutam.

**Gita 6.27**

> Thus, ever engaged in making the mind steadfast in spiritual communion
> and having all the impurities of the mind effaced thereby, the Yogin
> easily experiences the intense Bliss of contact with Brahman.

**Gita 6.28**

**Is loving other human beings wrong ? Can loving other human beings create attachment ?**

A person can love other human beings. That is not wrong. However, that will lead to suffering through repeated rebirths in this Samsara.

**Freedom from rebirth in the eternal cyclic Samsara**

> He who, with a mind undistracted by other things, thinks of Me
> constantly every day – to the Yogi thus ever-attuned, I am easy of
> attainment, O son of Prtha!

**Gita 8.14**

> **No more is re-birth, no more this home of transience and misery**, for
> those great-souled ones who have attained to supreme perfection by
> realizing Me.

**Gita 8.15**

> All the worlds from the realm of Brahma down to the earth are subject
> to re-birth. But, O Arjuna, one who has attained to Me is never
> reborn.

**Gita 8.16**

**What would be the attitude towards other human beings for a person who loves only God?**

The attitude will be that of **same-sightedness** which is vastly superior to love.

> The man of spiritual insight, established in same-sighted-ness, sees
> the Self as residing in all beings and all beings as resting in the
> Self.

**Gita 6.29**

> He who sees Me in all beings, and all beings in Me – to him I am never
> lost, nor he to Me.

**Gita 6.30**

> Established in the unity of all existence, a Yogin who serves Me
> present in all beings, verily abides in Me, whatever be his mode of
> life.

**Gita 6.31**

> O Arjuna! In My view that **Yogi is the best who, out of a sense of
> identity with others on account of the perception of the same Atman in
> all, feels their joy and suffering as his own.**

**Gita 6.32**